# How to release (get-item c:\temp\a.log).OpenRead() from lock status?

Tags: powershell

I use PowerShell command `(get-item c:\temp\a.log).OpenRead()` to test what happen with the file.

After file is opened to read, if I issue `(get-item c:\temp\a.log).OpenWrite()`, it will return the following error

```
Exception calling "OpenWrite" with "0" argument(s): "The process cannot access the file
'C:\temp\a.log' because it is being used by another process."  
+ (get-item c:\temp\a.log).OpenWrite()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IOException
```

How can I release the `OpenRead()` status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to explain why you're seeing this behavior when you open a file with `.OpenRead()` and then again with `.OpenWrite()`, it's caused by *[sharing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx)* (or lack thereof), not [locking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.filestream.lock.aspx).  Sharing dictates what kind of access is allowed for other streams opened from the same file while the current stream is still open.

[`OpenRead`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/io/fileinfo.cs.html#950e0a34bec823b1) and [`OpenWrite`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/io/fileinfo.cs.html#4e528f9f26896692) are convenience methods that wrap the [`FileStream` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.filestream.filestream.aspx); `OpenRead` creates a read-only stream with read sharing allowed, and `OpenWrite` creates a write-only stream with *no* sharing allowed.  You may notice that there is another method called simply [`Open`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.fileinfo.open.aspx) with overloads that allow you to specify the [access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/4z36sx0f.aspx) (second parameter) and sharing (third parameter) yourself.  We can translate `OpenRead` and `OpenWrite` to `Open`, thus...

```
$read = (get-item c:\temp\a.log).OpenRead()
# The following line throws an exception
$write = (get-item c:\temp\a.log).OpenWrite()
```

...becomes...

```
$read = (get-item c:\temp\a.log).Open('Open', 'Read', 'Read')           # Same as .OpenRead()
# The following line throws an exception
$write = (get-item c:\temp\a.log).Open('OpenOrCreate', 'Write', 'None') # Same as .OpenWrite()
```

Either way you write it, the third line will fail to create a write-only stream because `$read` will only allow other streams to read as well.  One way to prevent this conflict is to close the first stream before opening the second:

```
$read = (get-item c:\temp\a.log).Open('Open', 'Read', 'Read')           # Same as .OpenRead()
try
{
    # Use $read...
}
finally
{
    $read.Close()
}

# The following line succeeds
$write = (get-item c:\temp\a.log).Open('OpenOrCreate', 'Write', 'None') # Same as .OpenWrite()
try
{
    # Use $write...
}
finally
{
    $write.Close()
}
```

If you really do need a read-only and a write-only stream to be open on the same file simultaneously, you can always pass your own values to `Open` to allow this:

```
$read = (get-item c:\temp\a.log).Open('Open', 'Read', 'ReadWrite')
# The following line succeeds
$write = (get-item c:\temp\a.log).Open('OpenOrCreate', 'Write', 'Read')
```

Note that the sharing goes both ways: `$read` needs to include `Write` in its sharing value so that `$write` can be opened with `Write` access, and `$write` needs to include `Read` in its sharing value because `$read` is already open with `Read` access.

In any case, it is always good practice to call [`Close()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.stream.close.aspx) on any [`Stream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.stream.aspx) when you are done using it.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to release the lock status

I just invoke another command:

```
$s = (get-item c:\temp\a.log).OpenRead()
```

, then use

```
$s.close()
```

The file is not locked anymore

Answer (score 1):

I found previous post just works because the variable $s is just what I invoked $s = (get-item c:\temp\a.log).OpenRead() earlier.

So $s is just the object that need to be closed.

I try the following test to make it more clearly.

case1:

```
$a = (get-item a.txt).OpenRead()  #the a.txt is locked
$a.Close() #a.txt is unlocked
```

case2:

```
$a = (get-item a.txt).OpenRead()  #the a.txt is locked
$b = (get-item a.txt).OpenRead()
$a.Close() #a.txt is locked
$b.close() #a.txt is unlocked
```

case3:

```
 $a = (get-item a.txt).OpenRead()  #the a.txt is locked
 $a = "bbb"  #the a.txt is locked for a while, finally it will unlock
```

For case3, it seems the system will process the dangling object, then release the lock status.